# Foreach Loop using KVP to iterate through a Multi-Dimensional List

Tags: c#, list, foreach, visual-studio-2013, keyvaluepair

I want to use a foreach k, v pairs loop to run through a multidimensional list, and output those values elsewhere. Here is the code:

```
public class LogTable
{
    public string FunctionName { get; set; }
    public string LogTime { get; set; }
}

public class TableVars
{
    public List<LogTable> loggingTable { get; set; }
    public TableVars()
    {
        loggingTable = new List<LogTable>();
    }
    public void createLogList()
    {
        loggingTable = new List<LogTable>();
    }
}

foreach( KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in tablevars.loggingTable)
{
    // output would go here. I haven't looked it up yet but I assume it's something 
    // along the lines of var = k var2 = v? Please correct me if I'm wrong.     
}
```

When I run my mouse over 'foreach' I get a warning saying - 'Cannot convert type 'DataObjects.LogTable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair. How can I resolve this issue, or is there a more efficient way to accomplish the same goal?

Thanks!

I should have added more context, sorry. I'm trying to return the two different values inside the properties 'FunctionName' and 'LogTime' which I have added via:

var tablevars = new TableVars();
tablevars.loggingTable.Add(new LogTable { FunctionName = errorvalue, LogTime = logtime });

To specify more accurately, the intention of the foreach k, v loop was to grab every distinct property of FunctionName and LogTime and input them into a database in SQL Server. This is why the distinction between k, v (or FunctionName, LogTime) is important. Again, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can resolve the issue by changing the foreach loop variable to a `LogTable` as you are iterating over a `List<LogTable>`. Why do you think it should be a `KeyValuePair<string,string>`?

Comment: How do I specify between the two different parameters in the List, in that case? I'm visualizing it like-so:

Comment: What's wrong with simply accessing the properties?

Comment: Oops, sorry. I'm visualizing it like this - LogTable = { key = "key" value = "value" } and I thought that is what was accomplished by utilizing the LogTable Class with FunctionName and LogTime

Comment: I'm trying to add the two different properties into two different columns in a separate database. They need to be distinct. If I can do that without using k, v, how would I do so? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Question updated to reflect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `KeyValuePair<>`, because you don't enumerate a `Dictionary<>`. But you don't need to, simply do this:

```
foreach(LogTable logTable in tablevars.loggingTable)
{
    // do whatever with logTable.FunctionName and logTable.LogTime   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either change your `foreach` to iterate through `List<LogTable>`

```
foreach( LogTable lt in tablevars.loggingTable)
 {...}
```

OR

Use a `KeyValuePair` instead of creating class `LogTable`

```
public class TableVars
{
    public Dictionary<string,string> loggingTable { get; set; }
    public TableVars()
    {
        loggingTable = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    }
    public void createLogList()
    {
        loggingTable = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
}

foreach( KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in tablevars.loggingTable)
{
    //loggingTagle is now a KeyValuePair 
}
```

Comment: I updated my question to provide some context. Do you think a Dictionary is better in this instance than a List?